# Android Studio: Debug Google Maps application on device

Tags: android, google-maps

*Android Sudio 2.3.3 Windows 7*

I am only getting a blank screen, with *Google* at the bottom, and no map or tiles. I have run *Keytool* on the debug.keystore 
and have a valid API key from Google which is in the AndroidManifest (name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"). I have a real 
device connected via USB cable. I have no *google_maps_api.xml* files anywhere. There are red messages in Logcat such as:

```
    Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
  ...Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
  Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
  Ensure that the following Android Key exists: (same as in AndroidManifest)
  API Key: 0gKmWT-U09vi2HR6t4K8V1vyFi9CMReRLqqS41A
```

I know thw app is running as the Toast messages appear on the device but no map. So presumably something needs adding to the Google
Developers Console, but the documentation on that is as clear as mud. Could somebody please advise me as to exactly what I must do as I am getting nowhere?

Comment: Have you enabled Google Maps API on the developer console?

Comment: Exactly how do I do that? I am not familiar with the developer console. Do I have to add the same API key there too?

Comment: It works now and this is what I did: IGNORE the API key that Google returns after sending the MD5 key. On Developer Console Add Credential, then click EDIT, select Android Apps and add the SHA1 key and package name. Put the generated key in the AndroidManifest. It is a pity that this is not clearly explained anywhere as it took me 3 days!

Comment: I believe it's documented here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#detailed-guides